# How to remove the tiny wired color from bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

This is how it looks like in light theme
[Light Theme Preview](https://i.imgur.com/NnYSZBx.jpeg)
(even though the bottom system bar had light icon even in light mode it's should be gray or something like that, whatever)
[Dark Theme Preview](https://i.imgur.com/9QJkz9B.jpeg)

In dark theme there's a different color behind the item I don't know where is that coming from.

Here's my code
[themes.xml](https://gist.github.com/kisonix/ba5ed608c969476d71143fb162919478)

values/styles.xml
`

```
<style name="Widget.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">

    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorSurface</item>

</style>
```

```
<style name="Widget.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">

    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

`

1. Can I change the bottom system bar icon color to gray in light them?
2. How can I remove that wired color Fig.2 from bottom navigation view in light theme? I just wanted to set the bottom navigation view background to match with the content screen's background.